# Convert array from with keys to without keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there an elegant way to convert the following json data to the desired data format below?

**original data**

```
{
   "data": [
        {
            "timestamp": 1385118121279,
            "value": 40
        },
        {
            "timestamp": 1385118301279,
            "value": 7
        }

    ]
}
```

**desired format**

```
[[1385118121279,40],[1385118301279,7]]
```

Comment: Yes, it's very easy with a simple `for` statement, or use `.map()` if you prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with this:

```
var transformed = originalObj.data.map(function(item){
   return [item.timestamp, item.value];
});
```

However, doesn't work in old browsers.

For all browsers including old ones:

```
var transformed = [];
for(var i in originalObj.data){
    var item = originalObj.data[i];
    transformed.push([item.timestamp, item.value]);
}
```

Cheers

Comment: for support in older browsers, jQuery also provides a `map` function

Comment: That's right. And many frameworks, too. But the asker didn't mention jQuery, also it's not in the question tags. Cheers ;)

Comment: agreed. Just adding the comment for those who have to support older browsers (like me)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by iterating over object and we can get the array we want.

```
var abc ={
   "data": [
        {
            "timestamp": 1385118121279,
            "value": 40
        },
        {
            "timestamp": 1385118301279,
            "value": 7
        }

    ]
};
var dataArray = [];
for (var key in abc.data) {
      if(abc.data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        dataArray.push(abc.data[key].timestamp);
      }
}
console.log(dataArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is "elegant", but anyway:

```
function obj2arr(obj){
    if(obj instanceof Array){
        var ret=[];
        for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
            if(typeof obj[i]=="object"){
                ret.push(obj2arr(obj[i]));
            }else{
                ret.push(obj[i]);
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }else if(typeof obj=="object"){
        var ret=[];
        var keys=Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
        for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
            if(typeof obj[keys[i]]=="object"){
                ret.push(obj2arr(obj[keys[i]]));
            }else{
                ret.push(obj[keys[i]]);
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }else{
        return obj;
    }
}
```

The following test:

```
console.log(obj2arr({
    "data": [{
        "timestamp": 1385118121279,
        "value": 40
    },{
        "timestamp": 1385118301279,
        "value": 7
    }]
}));
```

Outputs:

```
[ [ [ 1385118121279, 40 ], [ 1385118301279, 7 ] ] ]
```

[**Online demo**](https://eval.in/86528) (I'm surprised to see that the JS engine in `Ideone` doesn't support `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`)

Although **please be noted that** this is a recursive solution, so big objects may causes stack overflow...